# Designer workflow not sending email from dropdown field

Tags: designer-workflow

I have SharePoint Designer 2013, and I created a list workflow (2013). The recipients are stored in a list as DropDown field. When I create new item email are not going (either To or CC). Now surprisingly when I put the same code (CurrentItem:Approver) in body it fetches the correct email address.

When I keep myself in "CC" and Approver (Choice field value) in "To", TO field remains blank. But in the email body I get the correct email address.

When I manually provide the Approver email it works fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried verifying the format of the email address is not the issue, or making sure they are SharePoint users?

Comment: yes they are sharepoint users. and the email address format is correct.

Comment: Till the time I didn't find the resolution however I have done a workaround. I  created 2010 workflows where ever needed just to send emails. This annoying but worked. I am looking for resolution.